# Typesafe Activator commands don't work in CentOs

Tags: playframework, centos, typesafe-activator

Installed Typesafe Activator in CentOs, when typing any commands, command line displays a message

```
"killed"!
```

Java installed, I can not understand what was going on.

Comment: How did you install the Activator? What does `java -version` say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already answered on russian SO, but I think it would be well if I duplicate an answer in English:

I think you don't have enough memory. Let's try over another ssh-connection and type: 
free -m -s 1.

It will show amount of free memory, so you should also (in parallel terminal) type command that crashes with "killed". I think in that moment `free` will show that your memory is running out and (after process killing) there will be enough amount of memory again.

Some virtualization technologies (for instance OpenVZ) doesn't support swap space so you can try to move to virt tech that supports swap (for instance Xen)..